# How to remove screen lock previously set using Android Device Manager?

Tags: lock-screens, android-device-manager, textsecure

I placed a password on my phone from the online android device manager. I was just testing it out, and now I can't remove it. I keep reading go to settings > security > screen lock but that is not an option on my phone. I can remove android device manager from my device administrators, and under the password section the only option is to make passwords visible. I have always had a password on my phone but I do not want this type of password on my phone. Please help!

Comment: Can't you just disable it from `Android Device Manager`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Totally frustrating! I finally figured out the solution. Go to "Settings." Find the tab or section that shows your lock screen options. Mine was found under the "Display" tab. Choose "lock screen." Type in the password used in Android Device Manager. You should now be asked what Screen Security option you want to use. After selecting this option, you will be free from Android Device Manager's grip!